# Why am I getting a 400 bad request when I define different URIs for Authenticate and Request Token API calls?

Tags: ringcentral

I am writing a 3-legged authorization for integration with Ring Central based on this flow:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/authentication/auth-code-flow

Both step 1 (Request authorization code) and step (Exchange code for token) require that a "redirect_uri" parameter is provided. However if I define 2 different URIs for these steps I get a 400 Bad Request when I try to exchange code for token. Both URIs are defined in my Ring Central "OAuth Redirect URI" app settings.

[image]

When I use the exact same URL for both steps then the entire process works fine except that I end up being redirected back to the authentication callback URI. What am I missing here? Is this a limitation on the sandbox environment?

Comment: Is there a technical need to have two different URLs? One should be able to disambiguate between the two calls by looking at the parameters of the request. 

I have not encountered this issue before, but can certainly see how two different URLs, even if they are both listed in your OAuth Redirect URI list could have been implemented with this restriction. I think the OAuth flow uses the URI you initially pass into the process as the URI for that entire session...

(FYI I work at RingCentral)

Comment: @ByrneReese I suppose there is no technical need, and I guess you are correct that I can just catch response parameters from both requests in one of my URIs, I just feel it's a bit dirtier this way - I have to write some if/else block just to see which parameters I have in the response and which ones I don't. In any case, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ByrneReese I would also expect that your tutorial on this topic should specifically say that these URIs must match/be the same. I mean it's no big deal, I figured it out but it would've saved me some time.

Comment: So to clarify... our documentation here: https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/authentication/auth-code-flow details 2 steps in which a RedirectURI is specified: step 1 and 4. What is not clear is that these URIs need to be the same in both steps. I will confirm this on my end and get back to you and/or update documentation.

Comment: @ByrneReese Yup that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons RingCentral requires the RedirectURI that is initially transmitted in the initial loginURL to be the RedirectURI used throughout that authorization session. That is why you receive the HTTP Auth error.

The RingCentral Authentication Quick Starts provide as great starting place for an end-to-end OAuth flow. Check them out:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/authentication/auth-code-flow